# Animation in javascript works every other time

Tags: javascript

I get a dropdown-toggle `(id="actions")` with image `(id=imgAction)` in html. I added script in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var el = document.getElementById("actions");

    if (el.addEventListener)
        el.onmouseover = tadaAnimation;

    function tadaAnimation() {
        $(imgAction).toggleClass('animated tada');
    }

 });
```

and it works but every second time. Why it doesn't work every time I hover the dropdown-toggle.

Comment: Maybe add el.onmouseout = tadaAnimation; ...

Comment: You need to remove and re-add the class, not toggle it off and on.  "Toggle" means "If it's there, remove it. If it's not, add it."

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and native JS? also its really confusing that you are validating for `addEventListener` then using `onmouseover`. As you are using jQuery bind event using it.

Comment: It's `$("#imgAction")` not `$(imgAction)`.

Comment: @jeremy thille yes and no. OPs is probably faster, yours is more bulletproof

Comment: Both are working  $("#imgAction") and $(imgAction) also

Comment: What?? But isn't `$(imgAction)` expecting a defined variable? Won't it throw `imgAction is not defined` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I am just using it in Bootstrap Studio, I haven't plugged it to any background yet and when I go with mouse on dropdown then I see animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem area it that you are binding only `mouseover` event handler. You also need to attach `mouseout` event handler

Every time your mouse enters or leaves a child element, `mouseover` is triggered, but not `mouseenter`. So I would recommend you to use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`

As you are using jQuery bind event using it. I would suggest you to use [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function tadaAnimation() {
        $("#imgAction").toggleClass('animated tada');
    }
    $("#actions").hover(tadaAnimation, tadaAnimation)
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to add tadaAnimation to more elements?
Like:
$("#actions").hover(tadaAnimation, tadaAnimation)
$("#office").hover(tadaAnimation, tadaAnimation)?

Comment: @Michu93, Yes. And you can combine selectors like  `$("#office, #actions").hover(tadaAnimation, tadaAnimation)`

Comment: but then I have to change $("#imgAction"). I would like to add tadaAnimation separately to dropdowns and pass variable to function tadaAnimation(image)

Comment: @Michu93, if you have separate element, then you can use it like `$("#actions").hover(function(){ tadaAnimation(someElement)}, function(){ tadaAnimation(someElement)})`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var el = document.getElementById("actions");

if (el.addEventListener)
    el.onmouseover = tadaAnimation;
    el.onmouseout = tadaAnimation; // add this line, should works

function tadaAnimation() {
    $(imgAction).toggleClass('animated tada');
} });
```